# moving Laravel project between computers

Tags: laravel-5

I have been working on a laravel5 project on a computer , but now I want to continue on an other, but don't know how :(

I'm using wampserver and the project is in the "www" folder,  this is the error I'm getting when trying to open the project: " Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request"

Comment: after moving files to other computer, you need to use `composer update`

Comment: Use git to push or pull the code.
How to setup git visit
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: WampServer or wampserver, it does not matter on windows. Windows is case insesitive, while other systems are case sensitive, that was - for me - a reason why a Laravel project worked on one server but not on an other.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your error message is very vague, so it is hard to pinpoint the cause. I assume you just copy pasted all of the project files

Try these steps:

1. Make sure you copy all of the project files including the hidden ones(.env).
2. Prepare your destination computer as in http://laravel.com/docs/
3. Check you have all the necessary PHP extensions available in php.ini as in above link requirements. Also, watch your PHP version!
4. Install composer https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
5. When copied, go to your destination folder and run `composer install`.
6. Run php artisan key:generate from the command line.
7. Run php artisan cache:clear from command line

   ```
   http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php
   ```
8. Make sure your webserver is serving pages from project/public folder.

If laravel is failing, check the log file to see the cause

```
your_project/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Comment: Now, everything work just fine, I had some hidden files that weren't copied , still don't know  how still I copied the entire file o.O

thank you, un GRAND merci :)

Comment: In laravel 5.4 `generate:key` was changed to `key:generate`

Answer (score 24):

Copy the project folder and navigate terminal/cmd
just run following commands.

Create database and place the same name at `.env` file in laravel project folder

```
1. composer install
2. php artisan key:generate  
3. php artisan cache:clear
4. php artisan migrate
```

**UPDATE:** If you're getting

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong

in `app/config/app.php`, set debugging as **true** with:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)'
```

If you're getting the error

> No supported encrypter found. The cipher and/or key length are invalid

for some people it worked to do `cp .env.example .env` before (2).

Comment: This is specially good for those who clone Laravel projects using git.

Answer (score 4):

You would also have to create new storage link, because Laravel uses absolute path inside it.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32722141/3982831 Please follow this to resolve your problems. All people forget about permissions on folders.

Answer (score 0):

After you have done as Ademord answer, you might need to use refresh to your WAMP, XAMP or any other development stack you are using. I had the same issue plus changes were not reflecting in the front end. For example new routes in the web.php were not updating.