# Blank white page when finished uploading files to server laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, hosting

I have finished uploading files to server inside `demo` folder, but when i visited i got blank white page. when i visited `somedomain.com/demo` i got blank white page. Can anyone help me please. My folder directory start with  demo. Inside `demo`folder i have `app`,`bootstrap`,`config` etc folders.
 when i view storage/log file i got

```
[2015-09-20 06:38:00] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sidinsu\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClearCompiledCommand.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2015-09-20 06:52:16] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sidinsu\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClearCompiledCommand.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2015-09-20 06:53:23] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sidinsu\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClearCompiledCommand.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2015-09-20 06:58:28] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sidinsu\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClearCompiledCommand.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Comment: Pls read your errors... You have a call to undefined method -> fix it.

Comment: i have upgrade php version above 5.5 and now i got error                                                  
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/app/Http/helpers/Backend/helpers.php' (include_path='/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59

Comment: @RanjeetKarki , did you solve your problem?

Comment: yes problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

The blank page suggests a 500 error and your logs back this up.

Looking at your logs it is an issue with the `vendor/compiled.php` file.

Just delete this file, run `composer update`, and then `php artisan optimize` after the update to rebuild `compiled.php`.

On a side note, the URL to view this should be somedomain.com/demo/public as this is where the `index.php` file is located - unless you have already dealt to this.

Comment: when i write something to index.php and go to somedomain.com/demo ,it display written text

Comment: OK - but dealing with the issue at hand, have you deleted the file and run the commands?

Comment: i should again download files from server and follow your steps,it takes time

Comment: OK, let me know how it goes.

Comment: i got blank white page

Comment: Are you downloading the files, running the commands and then uploading or removing the file and running the commands on the server?

Comment: i have upgrade php version above 5.5 and now i got error                                                  
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/app/Http/helpers/Backend/helpers.php' (include_path='/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59

Comment: it can be run in c-panel??

Answer (score 0):

When you move Laravel 5 to a production server please do the following:

Change permissions of storage and bootstrap folders to 0755 or 0777 `chmod -R 0777 storage/` 
composer install
composer update
artisan cache:clear

This will resolve your dependencies and make laravel functional. 
When you get packages conflicts after doing the above steps remove the packages from app/config/app.php and delete their folders from vendor and run composer update.

**Also make sure you will meet Laravel 5 minimum requirements. PHP 5.5.9 is required.**

Comment: i changed permission of storage and bootstrap folder to 777 on right click to folder,i got change permission and chnaged

Comment: and? what is the result? Can we connect on skype or something so I can help you and understand the problem better? I guess you don't understand either what I'm saying.

Comment: What do you get now? have you checked the php version? for laravel 5 is 5.5.9

Comment: i have upgrade php version above 5.5 and now i got error                                                  
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/app/Http/helpers/Backend/helpers.php' (include_path='/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/womenactorg/public_html/siddhartha/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59

Comment: php composer.phar update - run this in shell or composer update. Do you have composer installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90413/discussion-between-ranjeet-karki-and-alexander-nicholas-popa).