# Laravel computer-computer migration session errors

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Hello after copying my laravel project to other computer, when i try to php artisan serve it on it, I get this message on localhost:8000. Could anyone please explain what does it mean ? I deleted .json session file but still i got nothing.

```
   Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1 InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [index2] not found.

    in FileViewFinder.php line 137

    at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('index2', array('C:\Users\chris-basic\Desktop\p\resources\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79

    at FileViewFinder->find('index2') in Factory.php line 174

    at Factory->make('index2', array(), array()) in helpers.php line 855

    at view('index2') in web.php line 20

    at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}() in Route.php line 176

    at Route->runCallable() in Route.php line 147

    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 644

    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41

    at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65

    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49

    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64

    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37

    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59

    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104

    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 646

    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 620

    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 598

    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267

    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46

    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33

    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104

    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149

    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116

    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

    at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\public\index.php') in server.php line 21

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1 ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111: file_put_contents(C:\Users\chris-basic\Desktop\p\storage\framework/sessions/y4WU6ifJfcMd2ffoFyIZebwPw5ZCJyRxwHMLds2V): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

    in Filesystem.php line 111

    at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'file_put_contents(C:\Users\chris-basic\Desktop\p\storage\framework/sessions/y4WU6ifJfcMd2ffoFyIZebwPw5ZCJyRxwHMLds2V): failed to open stream: No such file or directory', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php', '111', array('path' => 'C:\Users\chris-basic\Desktop\p\storage\framework/sessions/y4WU6ifJfcMd2ffoFyIZebwPw5ZCJyRxwHMLds2V', 'contents' => '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', 'lock' => true))

    at file_put_contents('C:\Users\chris-basic\Desktop\p\storage\framework/sessions/y4WU6ifJfcMd2ffoFyIZebwPw5ZCJyRxwHMLds2V', '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', '2') in Filesystem.php line 111

    at Filesystem->put('C:\Users\chris-basic\Desktop\p\storage\framework/sessions/y4WU6ifJfcMd2ffoFyIZebwPw5ZCJyRxwHMLds2V', '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', true) in FileSessionHandler.php line 83

    at FileSessionHandler->write('y4WU6ifJfcMd2ffoFyIZebwPw5ZCJyRxwHMLds2V', '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') in Store.php line 262

    at Store->save() in StartSession.php line 88

    at StartSession->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in Kernel.php line 176

    at Kernel->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in index.php line 58

    at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: first, does `C:\Users\chris-basic\Desktop\p\resources\views` is the correct path? does `index2` does exist?

Comment: index2 exists, and this is my path from the first computer, but i don't understand why it's saved in project

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697861/moving-laravel-project-between-computers

Comment: throw `php artisan view:clear`, `composer dump-autoload` @WinithePooh

Comment: Did that, and now i know that at last route.php  works, i dunno why it's not finding my views

Comment: Its all about integrity. use `git`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to move projects is through `git`.
If you want to do it manually, copy all folders except `vendor`, then run `composer install`.

Comment: no, i don't think *redownloading* all dependencies for moving project files around is an obligatory. not to mention the stacktraces tell us about that it can't find some files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mirceac21. Best way is through `git`.

If you do not prefer it, it would be safer to `archive` the project without the `vendor` directory and migrate and then run `composer install`.

Laravel is a framework so you need all the files in correct order to perform as one. So you need to keep it's integrity. Therefor the perfect solution would be `git`. So why you waist time by doing other stuff?