# Laravel login keep failing

Tags: laravel, authentication

im continuing someone else's code.
and have been trying to solve it for days.

its a running system using laravel.
then i move the system to another computer.

i manage to set it up using xampp following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697861/moving-laravel-project-between-computers)
but after i logged in, it kept giving me invalid login. ive check the database, the credentials is there and its correct.

i really do not how to trace where it went wrong, but i manage to get this trace ( i change the db name); the password went missing.

[Debug trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62755.png)

Name of the error

```
PDOException in PDOConnection.php line 43:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 
'myapp'
```

the error is due to i change the db username. ;)
im trying to figure out why it did not work when i moved it to another machine. 
if the hashed password is hidden in the trace, me guess  the trace ive shared will do no help. any ideas what i should do next? :_I

Update
LoginController

Update
As requested LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\MemberAuth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hesto\MultiAuth\Traits\LogsoutGuard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Member\Member;
use Response;
use App\Exceptions\Handler;
use App;
use App\Traits\ValidateCaptchaTrait;
use Lang;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers, LogsoutGuard {
    LogsoutGuard::logout insteadof AuthenticatesUsers;
}

use ValidateCaptchaTrait;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->redirectTo =  route('frontend.memberprofile.account');
    $this->middleware('member.guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
* Override the username method used to validate login
*
* @return string
*/
public function username()
{
    return 'agent_id';
}

/**
 * Show the application's login form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{

    return view('frontend.member.auth.login');
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('member');
}


public function login(Request $request)
{

        // Validate Captcha
    if(!$this->isValidCaptcha()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['captcha' => 'Invalid Captcha.'])->withInput();
    }

    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}


protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
   // return $request->only($this->username(), 'password') ;
   return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['active' => 1]);
}

    /**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    //
    if(!is_null( $user )){
        $user->lastlogin = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}


}
```

update 2

> `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ 
>       route('mem.lPost') }}">
>        {{ csrf_field(=) }}`

Comment: The password in the database is it hashed ?

Comment: yes ,....can u see the picture ive attached?

Comment: Why are you providing us with screenshots with the stacktrace, instead of the actual stacktrace in text format, in the question?

Comment: In the stacktrace, the values provided to the select are the id and active = 1 but no password, is that correct ?

Comment: Show us the error, not a link to a screenshot.

Comment: check the log file `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: sisve & dont panic : sorry if i put the  stacktrace in text format, in the question, it looks unreadable..  teeyo : yes. Ron van der heihden: lemme check

Comment: Ron: laravel.log does not have any new records. laravel-2017-09-20.log only has the database name error which i did deliberately, so that i can see the query made.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

make sure in .env file you specified the username and password for your database server correctly. in your error, it seems that you set your username to "" so it said Access denied for user ''@'localhost'. 
edit your .env file

```
DB_DATABASE=yourDBname
DB_USERNAME=root (or whatever your usrname), there is no possibly here to be null
DB_PASSWORD=yourpassword
```

Comment: Yes, actually i deliberately put the wrong authentication for the database, so that i can see what went wrong with the user authentication.

Comment: so what you got so far?

Comment: looking at  the stacktrace, from logincontroller, i pass the values right. then when it reached further, the password parameter is blank. is it because it is hashed?

Comment: can you edit your question with your logincontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration file or `.env` file if you're using `laravel 5.*`. Enter the correct credentials and you're good to go. Try to use default setup:

```
db database = myapp
username =
password = root
host = localhost
```

**Update:**

If you changed the `app key` of your application, the encrypted data stored in your database won't work anymore such as `passwords`, unless you put the `app key` back. So the solution for the accounts would be creating or updating the passwords using `bcrypt` helper or `Hash::make` so the `passwords` will store correctly with your new `app key`.

**Included your link:**

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/app-key

**Update 2:**

**Note:** *You can just put this in your controller where your method for homepage goes.*

```
$users = User::all();

if(count($users) > 0){
  foreach($users as $user){
    $user->update(['password' => bcrypt('janida')]);
  }
}

return "Success! All users has a password of janida.";
```

Comment: sorry my question may seemed confusing. im just wondering from the stacktrace, is there any fishy goin on with the parameter( username and password) being passed from logincontroller to the top?

Comment: Yes, if you got that error, then it seems that your database connection has a problem. You didn't set it up well.

Comment: @janida Is my answer correct for your question? Please feel free to comment if you have any question regarding this

Comment: jonjie, i deliberately put the wrong db_username. i needed to see the stacktrace.so u thinnk there s nothing wrong if the value of password is blank when it reached Connection?

Comment: No, password is also important for the connection, because it is a authentication/security for your database.

Comment: r u referring the password in the stacktrace line 3 or the one in the .env file?

Comment: What stacktrace are you referring to? the error? it's the same. It is just the visual representation of how laravel print the error if you have. Please let's stick to your question so we can step outside of it.

Comment: @janida Then, please tell me after you update your config file or your `.env` file if you're using laravel5.* Let's do one step at a time.

Comment: ok. i fixed it.it connected successfully. but i still cannot get into the system. It s an old running system. i just need to switch machine.when i key in the member id and password into the system, it says invalid.

Comment: @janida So now the only problem is you cannot login? Do you have any error for now?

Comment: So the only problem is you cannot login?

Comment: Yes. i have the username & passwords list, none works, it is the same as the ones in the database.the db connected successfully.

Comment: Did you changed your app key? If so, your accounts won't work. unless register them again.

Comment: Register another user because the password in your database may be `hashed`

Comment: i did the  php artisan key:generate. it will automatically change the one in .env right? or i have to change it manually? the current hashed password in the database is save with BCrypt. will it also become obsolete?

Comment: Oh no!  your password is connected to your `key`, so that your passwords will not be match with the password in your database. you have to generate new password using `Hash::make` or `bcrypt()` if you already changed the `key`.

Comment: Sorry, i was out of town and there was no internet. so Jonjie, if that the case, maybe its because by regenerating new app_key made all the password unusable. what if i dont change the app_key after i moved site to another machine, shud it be ok? and while searching on this issue,i came across this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/app-key.

Comment: @janida Exactly!  That's why I'm asking you if you changed your app key. Because all your encrypted data won't work such as passwords

Comment: 1. i put back original app_key in .env ,restart server  2. i copy  back the whole application folder, edit database credentials,,clear cache, restart server.

Comment: is there a way i can just  update the password at the database app?

Comment: Yes! just run a `save()` or `update()` method in laravel with the `password` you want. I will update my answer.

Comment: @janida Keep in mind that **all** your users will be updated the same password.

Comment: i can do this in the phpmyadmin?

Comment: No, that is a laravel functionality. You may do it in the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

- copy the project to the new system
- run command "comoser update" via terminal
- run command "php artisan key:generate"
- set .env file
- set your username, password and db name
- restart apache2 ($ sudo service apache2 restart - if its ubundu 14)

sample env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yourDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=yourpassword

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

if there is some cache issue run below commands

- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear

Comment: ok.i did all of the above except dump-autoload and config:clear. and i have try running it all. I still cannot login to the system. the authentication failed. it was a running system. there's no log saying anything is wrong with the system. the database connected successfully. . :(

Comment: @janida  is the 'mod rewrite rule' on ?? pls check, it must be enabled to run htaccess file

Comment: use commands "sudo a2enmod rewrite"  then "service apache2 restart" or "systemctl restart apache2" . also set override all in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf . refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Done uncomment rewrite rule and set override all and clear all cache.but to no avail. :(

Comment: if you are using 'post' method dont forget to pass csrf token, and if you are not using csrf token , comment it from 'Kernel.php' .... <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: i think it already has that. i ve added that part in my question.