# Laravel project copied from working project in same server isnot working

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have searched and did research to solve my problem but I could not.

I am working on laravel 5.1 .

I have working project [Working project](http://www.paracosma.tv)  on server and I just copied it in server.

Now, previous project is working fine but newly  [copied project](http://demo.paracosma.com) **login** isn't working.

I have checked the file permission in project and I have assigned access right to needed file as per my knowledge .

I did composer update.

I googled it hard but couldn't solved it .

Comment: [May be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697861/moving-laravel-project-between-computers)

Comment: @SagarGautam i do bro ...  hi .. i have problem in same project in same directory one is working another isnt

Comment: Did  you clear caches ?

Comment: And another thing, can you add the error encountered it'll be helpful to understand your problem

Comment: On server ?? or what ???

Comment: you've mentioned **login not working** in above question  what's the error ?

Comment: Signup is adding user credential in database but isnot logging in ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165265/discussion-between-pravin-poudel-and-sagar-gautam).

Comment: Make sure you update composer & update your ".env"  file in server

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati thanks for ur comment .. I did composer update and .env file is also .. what do you mean by update .env file ?? what do i have to update ??

Comment: @pravinpoudel you need to update the env variables like     
APP_NAME,APP_ENV,APP_KEY,APP_DEBUG,APP_LOG_LEVEL,PP_URL,
DB_CONNECTION,DB_HOST,DB_PORT,DB_DATABASE,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,

Comment: Try this `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`