# PHP artisan returns access denied for database connection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I transferred a Laravel project based on [moving Laravel project between computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697861/moving-laravel-project-between-computers) 

Everything was fine at the first look. I could install the composer without any problems, then I set my environmental variables in my .env such as database name, database user and so on.

When I started using the following command,

```
php artisan cache: clear
```

I got these two errors,

> In Connection.php line 664:
>   
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Acess denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where tabale_schema = *** and table_name = ****)
>
> In Connector.php line 67:
>   
>   SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes)

Further Information:

1. It seems .env has not been read by the application because when I browse the homepage of the app, I got Whoops error which shows environmental variable is empty.[image: empty var]
2. I tested my database connection such as its username, password, and other parameters, I know they are working properly.

In the end, I attached a photo in order to elaborate on the issue.[image: issue]

3. Interestingly, in my .env file, DB_DATABASE value is "nlp" and DB_USERNAME equals "Javad" but as you can see in the errors, they are not working, and the Artisan assumes the root as the user!

Comment: Do you have the database and the database user on the new environment?

Comment: I entered to the DB with the user and password successfully then I got the list of databases, finally I could see the name of DB which I am working on!

Comment: Try to delete the configuration cache manually. To do so, delete: `bootstrap/cache/config.php` (or rename it to keep it as a backup).

Comment: Could you also provide the exact steps that you made from start until the error? Did you installed the exact same version of the packages or you did a fresh install of Laravel and more the old code? Which version of Laravel are you on?

Answer (score 0):

After you move a Laravel project to another location, The first thing you have to do is regenerate `APP_KEY` in the `.env` file by running the command from your application root directory:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that, you reconfigure your cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Additionally, make sure all your database parameters in your `.env` file and `config/database.php` are correct and the same as your previous Laravel setup - You can change them manually and then reconfigure your cache as shown above. If not (for instance, the database name is changed), you may have to rerun your database migrations and seeders again:

```
php artisan migrate
```

and

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: I mentioned in the 2nd part of my further information which I tested DB connection and they're working properly!

Comment: From your post, it means you have not setup the user "Javad" to have `read` access to the database "nlp".  if you have phpmyadmin or mysql workbench, you can cross check this.

Comment: the problem isn't your `.env` file. You must go to your database directly either through console or any other user interface and make sure that there is a user named "Javad" that has `read` and `write` access to an existing database schema named "nlp"

Comment: what type of database do you use?

Comment: Dude, I checked permissions, I granted the user to my DB and it has complete permissions to CRUD over the tables.

Comment: Then try running your query outside your laravel application.  Use the database console or a query script in Phpmyadmin, to see if you get same error

Comment: I tried it in console, interestingly it says, unknown column 'nlp' in where clause.
I tested this query: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema=nlp and table_name=page;

Comment: I put nlp and pages in double quotations sth like "" then it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195812/discussion-between-joyebright-and-udo-e).

Answer (score 0):

I think the configuration files are not writable by the apache user, considering you are using apache. Make sure you have given write permission to bootstrap/cache for the user. This directory contains the cached configuration files.If that is the case the congratulations will be loaded from here and your previously used configuration will be loaded which may be causing the issue.

Also you need to give write permission to the storage directory too. As there is the log file and apache user needs to write on that too.

Comment: I changed the permission of bootstrap/cache to 777 but again I got the same errors!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Go to the project path `project_name\bootstrap\cache` folder and remove the marked file `config.php` from the mentioned folder.
[image]

**Step 2:** Run the following command

```
 composer dump-autoload
 php artisan clear-compiled

 php artisan config:clear
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:cache
```

I hope that it will work now!

Answer (score -1):

Open the `.env` file and edit it. Just set up correct DB credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Your Database Username, If no username has been set then by default there is a root as a username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password, If no password is set on the database, clear it
```

After completion of `.env` edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

**If there is still the same error then try another possible solution.**

I had also face the same problem, I tried all the possible answers in StackOverflow but nothing could help me, this solution worked on the first try:

If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to restart your server after changing your `.env` file values.

I found this solution from here [laravel.io](https://laravel.io/forum/02-14-2015-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-the-user-homesteadlocalhost-password-yes) (Read the solution of Byjml)

Comment: As I wrote, I tested all of these steps and I got the same errors!